# Area of the city, I have amenities, roads and and admin relations

Tags: postgis

I am a complete beginner in spatial data and I do not know how to calculate the area of the city having amenities, roads and admin relations in postgres database. I tried searching the internet, but the answers I found are based either on the contour of the city, or a given polygon, or postal codes. I do not see a possibility of using these solutions in my case.
Here is my data, the city I am looking for is called Kraków (of Cracow). Here is my data in ESRI shapefiles format.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12snSgNc4SrtG6x0HeBMFIzvYH8Wfsl_j/view?usp=sharing

Here is the same data but with created sql files.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1opyg0njPHI2L2jlrlQ6nnQmxrkCijYao/view?usp=sharing

I bought the courses on Udemy, but it is going to take some time before I watch all of them. I know that I should use ST_Area function, but I do not know what to put as arguments.

I should probably have a polygon, but how to create it?

I have points, but how can I know which point belongs to Krakow, if there is no column postal code.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are trying to determine the area of the city of Kraków.

First, let's see what we can figure out from the shapefiles. The shapefile 'admin.shp' contains a polygon. One of the fields for the polygon is named "osm_id". This suggests the source of the data is OpenStreetMap. There is also a field "type" with the value "administrative" and "admin_leve" (presumably admin_level before truncation) with the value 6.

According to the [OpenStreetMap wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/index.php?title=Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative&uselang=en-GB), administrative boundaries are

> Subdivisions of areas/territories/jurisdictions recognised by governments or other organisations for administrative purposes.

Therefore, we would expect a city boundary to be labelled an administrative boundary. Now, what does the level 6 mean?

That same wiki page also helpfully includes a table that identifies the types of boundaries associated with different admin levels, split up by country. You've got a level 6 in Poland. From the table:

> powiaty (counties) - some cities have county status - in OSM their borders have both relations - one as a city and second as a county

So, your polygon is a county. But might be a city too. Let's check OSM directly.

Search for "Kraków" at [openstreetmap.org](http://openstreetmap.org) then activate the 'Query Features' tool (arrow with question mark) and click somewhere in the centre of the city. You will get a list of the **Nearby features** and **Enclosing features** on the left of the screen:
[image: OSM screen capture]

The list of enclosing features includes "City Boundary Krakow". Clicking on that one highlights it on map:
[image: OSM screen capture]

That looks very similar to the boundary in admin.shp and does have an admin level of 8 ("cities, towns and villages"). But we can do better. Scroll down on the left until you see "Part of" and select the relation listed there. That brings up a relation with admin level 7. Do that once more for admin level 6. Now we can see that the admin level 6 (county) and admin level 8 (city) polygons are indeed the same:
[image: OSM screen capture]

As such, you should be able to go ahead and determine the area of the city of Kraków using ST_Area and the polygon in the admin.shp.